# How to make a coordinates that will cut by a diamond by background-image?

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

I have a box coordinates that I've created but I don't know how to make it like a half diamond things.
Here is the sample code function

```css
section {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #111;
    background-image:
    linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.575) 1px, transparent 1px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255,255,255,.575) 1px, transparent 1px);
    background-size: 10% 10%,5% 5%;
}
```

```html
<section>
</section>
```

But I don't know how to make it like a half diamond coordinates.. Is there anything possible I can do this?

Comment: You want something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/nws6prym/

Comment: yes something like that but not that how the it structured the code.